# How to capture feature selection event using FeatureSelectedEventHandler in MapXtreme?

Tags: mapinfo, asp.net, mapxtreme

I am trying to implement functionality, where I need to run a piece of code when selection of a feature(point feature selection with mouse click) happens. 
I am using PointSelectionCommand (i.e., javascript clientcommand) and PointSelection(i.e., C# class command) provided in MapXtreme SDK. The code I tried is below:

```
public event MapInfo.Tools.FeatureSelectedEventHandler OnFseh;        
private void selectedEvents(object sender, FeatureSelectedEventArgs e)
{

}

private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.OnFseh += new FeatureSelectedEventHandler(selectedEvents);
}
```

the problem is control is not going into the selectedEvents method when I select a point feature on map.